# Xcode 5 does not copy static library files during build process

Tags: c, xcode, static-libraries

i´ve created a static library (c) with xcode 5 which can be build an used fine.

However, at the build settings there are some parameters which intends to allow direct installation into the system, which means copy the *.a file into /usr/local/lib and copy the *.h file into /usr/local/include.

I´ve tried a couple of hours with several configurations but all i´ve achieved so far is within the Release directory a usr/local/include subdir with my h-file in it.

Can anyone give me a hint how xcode 5 can be configured for automatic installation or did i missunderstand the settings?

Thanks and kind regards

Solick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set where to copy the file on install

[image]

set deployment location to ALWAYS use the install path (even during building)

[image]

Comment: thanks but a static library consists of two parts, the .a file and the h files. As far as i can see there is no automatic installation of the complete lib files? By the way: Why not fill the path into the line "installation directory"? seems to be very confusing. Mybe because xcode is not really ment to produce ansi c programs?

Comment: the headers files aren't part of the lib but they are often copied (and so does Xcode) during building

Comment: and I AM setting the install path -- thats the point. install path & deployment location

Comment: but it won't copy the lib into libs and the headers into headers/libName -- like it is 'convention' (even if ansi C has nothing todo with it)

Comment: just add a script phase to the build and move the output to the right folders :)

Comment: i think i will do with some post build script to move them, should be the most simple way. Thanks!